# Got error about app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I got an error when I build an object . There are some message

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

what can I do ?!

Answer (score 0):

Change your gradle to the latest version in project level build.gradle !

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Comment: my classpath is com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 , but it still not work

Comment: can you post the full logcat!

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Clean` and `Rebuild` project solved my problem.
Hope this helpful. 
 
If this senario not solve yet, may be have varied reasons and suggest some ways to solve it like below:

- Check mismatch of Resources
- Check missing attributes
- Check Duplicate of Resources
- Renaming the extension from .jpg to .png

  And at the final `Clean` and `Rebuild` or maybe `Invalidate Caches and Restart` may be help you.

Comment: @JeffLiu Have changed recently your Resources? see my edit.

Comment: yes , I have already done that , but it still not work for me